# waiting till the scheduled "at job" finishes then continue the script

Tags: linux, bash

is there any way to wait until the at job is finished then to echo hello ?

```
           if [[ condition ]]; then
              echo "bash ${CommandLine}" | at now + ${Interval} minutes
           fi
           echo 'hello'
```

I tried wait but it doesn't help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sesms to defeat the point of `at`, which is to run something later *without* having to wait for it. What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I call recursively "at job" and then print "failed"if none of the retries was successful. So would like not to print "failed" until several  retries

Comment: But why not just `sleep` between tries? If you want to wait for the job, and check its exit status, `at` really seems like the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: I got it. thank you very much!